# How to get current configuration in old hadoop api's reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapr

In the new Hadoop api, I can get the config from `context`.

But now I'm using the old api, how do I get the current configuration in old map/reduce's reduce?

Comment: the old api version is 0.20

Answer (score 0):

In the old API, there is a configure method (similar to the setup in the new API), from which you can get the conf as follows:

```
public void configure(JobConf conf) {
    int test = conf.getInt("test", 0));
    String testString = conf.get("testString", "default");
}
```

You can also use this method to get the DistributedCache (deprecated in the new API).